# stuck Database design small MYSQL Application

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm now designing a database for a new project.

[image]

the database is still in planing. I have now a think blockade.

Let me explain my small application first

there are 3 windows

1. Selection if you visit the event as guest or as subscriber.
2. On the second window you can fill all you personal infos (name etc. ). On this site the user select a Programm for morning and on lunch time he can have lunch or he can make a programm. After lunch he can select his programm for afternoon (afternoon and morning has total 4 programms. Programms you select in the morning you can't visit on afternoon (the two programms on lunch time are different)). 
   The amount of people who can visit the programm is also limited.
3. Checkout

My question is how can can i design my database for step 2? I want to see how many free seat a programm has and how many programms are booked on a ticket. Please remember in a Ticket you can visit 2 programms (without lunch 3 Programms).

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: You have described your app from a process centered point of view.  That's a natural way to describe an app.  Database design requires a data centered point of view.  What you need to do is to revisit your app from a data centered point of view and figure out what the data requirements are on your database.  Those requirements will drive the database design.

Comment: Keep in mind that order is a reserved word in MySQL and you will have to backtick it all the time to avoid errors.